# retornar linha inteira a partir do menor valor de uma coluna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou precisando que meu `DataFrame` retorne a linha a partir do menor valor de uma coluna específica do mesmo `DataFrame`.

Tenho um `DataFrame` conforme ao ilustrado abaixo:

```
    cod.   valor
0    AA    0.890591
1    MS    0.659724
2    GG    -3.006995
3    GL    -3.450675
4    AM    -0.116057
```

Tentei utilizar o método `min` sendo: `menor_valor = (df['valor'].min())`, porém dessa forma só consegui o valor em si que é: `-3.450675`.

O que de fato estou precisando é que o programa consiga retornar duas variáveis onde uma seja o 'cod.' e a outra o 'valor'. Seguindo o `DataFrame` que mandei seria '**GL**' e '**-3.450675**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método idxmin para encontrar o índice da linha com o menor valor na coluna "valor", e depois usar esse índice para acessar os valores desejados na coluna "cod." e "valor".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cod.': ['AA', 'MS', 'GG', 'GL', 'AM'],
                   'valor': [0.890591, 0.659724, -3.006995, -3.450675, -0.116057]})

min_index = df['valor'].idxmin()
cod = df.at[min_index, 'cod.']
value = df.at[min_index, 'valor']

print(cod, value)
```

Este código retornará a saída desejada: 'GL -3.450675'